# Problem changing width and height of a div in css using @media only screen and (max-width)

Tags: html, css

I am working on a webpage and trying to make it mobile friendly or to work on other screen sizes. I was going to use css (@media only screen and (max-width:)) to change the width and heigh of a div containing four images in the form of a circle thumbnail.

HTML:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
   <img src="#" class="cover1">
   <img src="#" class="cover2">
   <img src="#" class="cover3">
   <img src="#" class="cover4">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumbnail{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 20px;
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.thumbnail img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.
.
.

@media only screen and (max-width: 1180){
    .thumbnail{ <-- does not work
        width: 150;
        height: 150;
    }
    .thumbnail img{ <-- works
        width: 75px;
        height: 75px;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the media query you set `width: 150;height: 150;` without `px` . Try adding that. Also the same in `max-width: 1180` and please do not use `float:left`. just use `flex` and ' play ' with it

Answer (score 0):

you missed using unit (for example: px) in @media, width and height:

```
        <style>
.thumbnail{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 20px;
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.thumbnail img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1180px){ --> you have to use px
    .thumbnail{ 
        width: 150px; --> you have to use px
        height: 150px; --> you have to use px
    }
    .thumbnail img{ 
        width: 75px;
        height: 75px;
    }
}
        </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the unit px to `(max-width:1180)` and the .thumbnail width and height values.

```css
.thumbnail {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.thumbnail img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1180px) {
  .thumbnail {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
  }
  .thumbnail img {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="#" class="cover1">
  <img src="#" class="cover2">
  <img src="#" class="cover3">
  <img src="#" class="cover4">
</div>
```

.